# How do I replicate Haskell's `scanl (+) 0 xs` in Rust?

Tags: haskell, rust

If I have an list of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I wanted to generate a cumulative sum list, in Haskell I would do the following:

```hs
> let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

> scanl (+) 0 xs
[0,1,3,6,10,15]
```

Trying to get this same behaviour seems unnecessarily troublesome in Rust.

```rust
let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let vs = vec![0]
    .into_iter()
    .chain(xs.iter().scan(0, |acc, x| {
        *acc += x;
        Some(*acc)
    }))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

The awkward `scan` behaviour of having to mutate the accumulator can be explained by a lack of GC. But, `scan` also does not include the initial accumulator value, necessitating the need to manually prepend a 0 at the front. This itself was troublesome, as I needed to prepend it with `chain` and `[0].iter()` didn't work, nor did `[0].into_iter()` and `vec![0].iter()`. It needed `vec![0].into_iter()`.

I feel like I must be doing something wrong here. But, what? Is there a better way to generate a cumulative sum? Is it back to a `for` loop?

Comment: Seems that Rust's ```scan``` isn't quite the equivalent to Haskell's ```scanl```; they had to ammend the documentation since it [confused people](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/49353/commits/f198b0acf512458bdbe5079d12414ff94b03f7ac)

Comment: "The awkward scan behaviour of having to mutate the accumulator can be explained by a lack of GC. " no

Comment: @Stargateur No? What's the reason then? The way I see it, if Rust wanted to implement Haskell's `scanl`' behavior, the closure would have to clone it's value because the value needs to go back into the accumulator as well as get returned in a list, and cloning would affect performance. So, the decision of whether to clone was pushed to the user of the API. For numbers, there's no need, just some awkwardness of `*acc += x; Some(*acc)`.

Comment: FWIW I have often found it quite annoying that Haskell's `scanl` has that extra element on the front. In almost all situations where `scanl` is actually useful I've found myself calling `drop 1` on the result.

Comment: @DanielWagner I can appreciate that perspective. I haven’t had to simply because the formulas I’m implementing use the initial value.

Comment: @DanielWagner why not use `scanl1` then.

Comment: @WillNess Because its type is too restrictive: the accumulator and the list element type must match.

Comment: @DanielWagner exactly; but that is what you get when prepending the initial element to the input list, just the same. I thought that was what you meant, from the conversation's context. the OP thought so too, it seems.

Comment: @WillNess You say "that is what you get". What is "that"? You say "the initial element". What is the initial element? I don't really understand what you're objecting to or why you think the OP misunderstood me.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not objecting to anything. It was a misunderstanding on my part. By "you" I meant "we" i.e. a generic user. the OP [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591730/how-do-i-replicate-haskells-scanl-0-xs-in-rust#comment99780481_56591730) they "use the initial value" (the `x` in `scanl g x xs`) (in response to your preceding comment) which I took as being contrasted with you supposedly not using it? that's how I understood their comment, and by consequence, yours. So I erroneously thought you meant `scanl1 g (x:xs)` instead, which doesn't even make much sense to me now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do that with [`successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut xs = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].into_iter();
    let vs = std::iter::successors(Some(0), |acc| xs.next().map(|n| n + *acc));

    assert_eq!(vs.collect::<Vec<_>>(), [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]);
}
```

Comment: That's not as concise and pure as Haskell, tho :P

Comment: Thanks. It's not an issue of being concise. It's the semantics. I rather like this solution, actually.

Comment: @Listerone `successors` is maybe the best iterator-related feature in the std lib.

Comment: There is no need to put this into a vector, and then turn it into an iterator. Just use the range syntax.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bdea2432d1155021fff86c0ac0e7aeb9)

Answer (score 9):

### Edit :

Despite the old version of this answer mimics the behavior of `scanl`'s intermediate form, the execution wasn't lazy. Updated the generic implementation from my old answer with [@French Boiethios's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593816/1601571).

This is the implementation :

```rust
fn scanl<'u, T, F>(op: F, initial: T, list: &'u [T]) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'u
where
    F: Fn(&T, &T) -> T + 'u,
{
    let mut iter = list.iter();
    std::iter::successors(Some(initial), move |acc| iter.next().map(|n| op(n, acc)))
}
//scanl(|x, y| x + y, 0, &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18dffab413c6adc57a307a3bd5b4ada7)

---

It can be easily implemented by a `fold`

For an `Add` operation:

```rust
let result = xs.iter().fold(vec![0], |mut acc, val| {
    acc.push(val + acc.last().unwrap());
    acc
});
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9913ba0a67b3ed0eb3155a555e5ab76a)

---

Here is the generic version :

```rust
fn scanl<T, F>(op: F, initial: T, list: &[T]) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: Fn(&T, &T) -> T,
{
    let mut acc = Vec::with_capacity(list.len());
    acc.push(initial);

    list.iter().fold(acc, |mut acc, val| {
        acc.push(op(val, acc.last().unwrap()));
        acc
    })
}
//scanl(|x, y| x + y, 0, &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=720ebfbf2174a0a49b09992bf6324db4)

Comment: instead of `res[res.len() - 1]` one could use `res.last().unwrap()`, which makes the intention more clear imho

Comment: Thanks. Using `fold` with a vector certainly works, but circumvents the whole purpose of the `scan` function.

Answer (score 2):

> The awkward scan behaviour of having to mutate the accumulator can be explained by a lack of GC.

There is nothing preventing Rust from doing what you ask.

Example of possible implementation:

```rust
pub struct Mapscan<I, A, F> {
    accu: Option<A>,
    iter: I,
    f: F,
}

impl<I, A, F> Mapscan<I, A, F> {
    pub fn new(iter: I, accu: Option<A>, f: F) -> Self {
        Self { iter, accu, f }
    }
}

impl<I, A, F> Iterator for Mapscan<I, A, F>
where
    I: Iterator,
    F: FnMut(&A, I::Item) -> Option<A>,
{
    type Item = A;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.accu.take().map(|accu| {
            self.accu = self.iter.next().and_then(|item| (self.f)(&accu, item));
            accu
        })
    }
}

trait IterPlus: Iterator {
    fn map_scan<A, F>(self, accu: Option<A>, f: F) -> Mapscan<Self, A, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(&A, Self::Item) -> Option<A>,
    {
        Mapscan::new(self, accu, f)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> IterPlus for T where T: Iterator {}

fn main() {
    let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let vs = xs
        .iter()
        .map_scan(Some(0), |acc, x| Some(acc + x));

    assert_eq!(vs.collect::<Vec<_>>(), [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]);
}
```